# ZF2 Child routes not working

Tags: php, routes, zend-framework2

After reading numerious articels about routing i'm still not able to get it to work.

When i do this i'm able to go to "/portal":

```
'portal' => array(
    'type' => 'Literal',
        'options' => array(
            'route' => '/portal',
            'defaults' => array(
                'controller' => 'Portal\Controller\Activities',
                'action' => 'index',
            ),
    ),
),
```

But When I add the child_routes like so:

```
'portal' => array(
    'type' => 'Literal',
        'options' => array(
            'route' => '/portal',
            'defaults' => array(
                'controller' => 'Portal\Controller\Activities',
                'action' => 'index',
            ),
    ),
    'may_terminate' => true,
    'child_routes' => array(
        'default' => array(
            'type' => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '[:controller[/:action]]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*'
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Portal\Controller',
                    'action' => 'index'
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

I'm still able to go to "/portal" but when I go to "/portal/activities/index" (which is the same) I get "Page could not be found".

Hope someone can help

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you actually trying to do. Create a route that will match a specific controller and action from the url params?

Comment: I would like to create a route with a module and an optional controller and action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The segment definition is not correct, a / is missing, so complete child route is currently /portal[:controller[/:action]]

Change it to :

```
'portal' => array(
    'type' => 'Literal',
        'options' => array(
            'route' => '/portal',
            'defaults' => array(
                'controller' => 'Portal\Controller\Activities',
                'action' => 'index',
            ),
    ),
    'may_terminate' => true,
    'child_routes' => array(
        'default' => array(
            'type' => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*'
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Portal\Controller',
                    'action' => 'index'
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```